# Why wasn't Najenda's background story shown in the anime?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

[Najenda](http://akamegakill.wikia.com/wiki/Najenda) is the head of the assassin group Night Raid. Her background story, regarding the events which leads to the amputation of her right arm and the lost of her right eye, is shown in chapter 39 of the manga, right after the events in Kyoroch in the previous chapter (which corresponds to episode 19 of the anime). However, her story is not shown in the anime.

Why didn't the anime show her background story? I think her background story complements the rest of the series very well and make it easier understand.

Comment: I think it has to do with how they only have a few episodes left to reach the conclusion of the story. They have to deal with Shura (since he was the one who sent Tatsumi and Esdeath to the beach from the summit), Budou (since he had a role in the capture of Tatsumi and Lubbock), and also Kurome (she was kinda half-dead from Chelsea's failed attempt at assassination, and she needed someone to put her to rest), not to mention the King and the Minister. Though I have to admit I don't know if they can actually squeeze the story in if they had tried.

Comment: It must just come from the facts that this is anime is here to do some advertising for the manga. So if you like the anime you go read the manga to learn more.
So they don't show everything, only things that are epic or really interesting and for other things like Najenda they only show you enough to make you wonder what happened to her and force to go buy the manga again to know more about it :) That's my point of view